# Where can I find an AS400 to Java interface?

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, interop

Does anyone have links and resources to connect to an AS400 from Java?

I remember years ago, somebody told me about a connector that simulates KeyStrokes from the keyboard and other "purest" approach that connected directly.

On the web I have found a lot of links, but I cannot find a complete product to do this (I am probably not using the right keywords).

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers:

What we are looking for is a way to access the data inside the AS400 and/or the screens it uses and expose them for other new applications re-use. Either as a webservice of some sort, or directly through Java ( and java will expose the operations using webservices )

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As per MicSim post, I've also found this link:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-as400/index.html

Comment: What? You're starting over? Are you going for 10000 again?

Comment: @mmyers: But the question is real.

Comment: @Oscar: I don't doubt it, but I'd never heard of an AS400 until just now, so I'm not going to be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably the Toolbox for Java™ & JTOpen from IBM. There is also an AS400 class in the toolbox for performing specific AS400 tasks. You can look [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/faqjdbc.html) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.toolbox.doc/as400obj.htm) for more details. Just googled it and hope it's helpful.

Comment: Use ProgramCall to call PGM's, CommandCall to call CMD's.  If you need to do screen scraping I _believe_ I've heard that the tn5250j project may allow you to peek at a session.

Answer (score 3):

IBM's 5250 screen-scraping technology was "WebFacing" - I would post a link but you're probably better off Googling it, since IBM's documentation is so scattered.  There are other technologies available too but: Screen-scraping was never anyone's favourite since typically you end up with something which, although it looks more up-to-date, actually is harder to use than a green screen and no more functional.  The 5250 is probably the single best data entry platform I've ever used - web forms in a browser are one of the worst.

As mentioned, jt400 is the way to go for most other things.  In particular:

JDBC - for all things SQL.  If you do it right and address your files as though they really are tables, it's a way to get away from the 400 entirely.

Record-level access - write Java programs using a similar database API to RPGLE (all those chains, setlls that 400 programmers love)

Call programs, system commands, manage resources (data queues, data areas, prints / spools, jobs etc etc)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This obviously depends on what you want to do, however if you want to simulate keystrokes across a network connection to an AS400 process then Expect4j may be the library you are looking for.

This is generally a really nasty hack though and there are frequently better ways to achieve your goals. What are you trying to do?

The expect4J library can be found [here.](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/) Expect was originally a unix command that allowed you to specify a string that you are expecting to see and then a string of characters to return. It was frequently used for automating logins etc and for screen-scraping applications.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to access AS400 and retrieve data. About the keystroke, what I heard was more like a library that capture the greenscreens and provide input/output for them. I don't remember the name of the library

Comment: The Expect library looks for particular strings and then sends specific responses and would certainly do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run Java on the AS/400 (or iSeries, or System i, or whatever IBM's marketing department has decided to call it this month), that's a supported language. You can access the pseudo-DB2 database directly. Or are you after some other form of integration?

Comment: More in the way to expose a legacy AS400 system and expose it to webservices of some sort. Or probably directly to java. Not really using it as a target platform

Answer (score 0):

Even better is the [TN5250j](http://tn5250j.sourceforge.net/) Console, which can be used to extract data from the AS/400.

Answer (score -1):

jacada makes tools to do what your looking for

http://www.jacada.com/